# C# how can I access an element in nested array

Tags: c#, .net

[image: Type of the array]

```
ReplyKeyboardMarkup replyKeyboardMarkup = new(new[]
                {
                 new KeyboardButton[]{ "January", "February", "March", "April"},
                 new KeyboardButton[]{ "May", "June", "July", "August"},
                 new KeyboardButton[]{ "September", "October", "November", "December"},
                })
```

I have the following code, where ReplyKeyboardMarkup is a custom class from telegram.Bot api from nuget packages.
How can I access a specified element, like first string in first KeyboardButton array (January)?

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?

Comment: I expacted it to be smth like:
universalLayout.Keyboard[i][j] = "smth new";
Or
universalLayout[i][j] = "smth new";

Comment: @Palamar66: And what happens when you try that?  What even is `universalLayout`?

Comment: Once you feed your collection to the `ReplyKeyboardMarkup` constructor, you are constrained to however that exposes the data. As this is not a class that's part of the standard library you'd have to at least specify what library you're using (a link to the NuGet package would be nice).

Comment: https://core.telegram.org/constructor/replyKeyboardMarkup just guessing

Comment: I specified it, but here is the link https://www.nuget.org/packages/Telegram.Bot

Comment: @Palamar66 that is a link to a nuget package, not to a definition of the `ReplyKeyboardMarkup` class.

Comment: It is a link right above my prev comment. But it is already an answer in an answer section

Comment: @Palamar66, you should include all the details in the question and not leave it to reader to trawl through the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the `Keyboard` property:

```
string january = replyKeyboardMarkup.Keyboard
        .FirstOrDefault()?.FirstOrDefault()?.Text;
```

The `Text` property comes from the `KeyboardButton` and is what you have specified.

You have commented that you want to access it as a real array, because you want to modify each button easily. Then you can use this approach:

```
KeyboardButton[][] kbButtonArray = replyKeyboardMarkup.Keyboard as KeyboardButton[][]
            ?? replyKeyboardMarkup.Keyboard.Select(x => x.ToArray()).ToArray();
```

Actually the try-cast already works in the current implementation, so no need for the LINQ query. But since it it's an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<KeyboardButton>>` that cast might fail in future.

Comment: Thx for answer, I should have specified, that I want to access the value in order to change it inside the Markup.

Comment: @Palamar66: What _value_ you want to access? Instead of `...?.Text` you can also select the button itself. Then you can modify it. `KeyboardButton firstButton = replyKeyboardMarkup.Keyboard.FirstOrDefault()?.FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: I want to get any value by passing it's index, like the first button row, third button
smth like replyKeyboardMarkup[0][2]

Comment: Yeah, that wasn't that obvious. Thanks for answer, I'll accept it in a minute.

Comment: then just call `replyKeyboardMarkup[0][2]` to get 2nd element of `{"January", "February", "March"}`, in you case this will be `"March"`